# What is Stochastic?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, definition, stochastic-calculus

I was looking through my course modules and I saw that in my 3-4th semester we do Stochastic. I tried to find out what it is on Google but I got even more confused. What is Stochastic and what does it relate to in Computer Science?

Comment: @Moo No I mean what is Stochastic as a subject, like Theoretical CS or Lambda Calculus etc ...

Comment: If not the same then very close to probability theory

Comment: @drhab And let's say that I want to take the course now **without** any knowledge of Algorithms or Data Structures but strong bases in Complex Analysis and Cryptography. Would it be possible?

Comment: I think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Stochastic" is an English adjective which describes something that is randomly determined - so it is the opposite of "deterministic". In a CS course you could be studying stochastic processes such as random walks or Markov chains.